# Selenium Webdriver for Windows 7 and mac OS

Tags: macos, selenium, windows-7

I am calling a node from my Win7 machine using :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -port 5557 -hub http://192.168.1.37:4444/grid/register/ -browser "browserName=internet explorer, version=ANY -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\ie\ie"
```

ie is the latest IE Driver from here http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.0/

But i always throws the exception that "The path to the driver executeable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property..." What the problem here? It worked at some point today....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parameter `-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\ie\ie"` and any `-D` parameters must now come before `-jar` so:

```
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\ie\ie -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -port 5557 -hub http://192.168.1.37:4444/grid/register/ -browser "browserName=internet explorer, version=ANY
```

Comment: Make sure the path you pass to `-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=` actually points to your `IEDriverServer.exe`

Comment: Apperently I am to dumb to add the .exe :D Thanks a lot Lucas! Is there a reason why on default safari and IE are not getting the "waiting for Element" - I know offtopic. But it´s worth a try

Comment: I'm not completely sure I know what you mean by that

Comment: Well problem solved anyways. Thanks again. Have a great evening/day/morning :)